# Under what circumstance will the SQLite database file got lost or destroyed?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I know that one instance where an App's SQLite file may be removed from the System is when the user uninstall the Application. Apart from this situation, under what circumstance(s) will the SQLite file get lost or be destroyed in the Android System?

Again, under what circumstance will the SQLite database file loose all it's content even if the App is not uninstalled?

Will there be an instance where the Android System does this?

Answer (score 0):

Settings -> App -> Data -> Clear Data would also delete the SQL. Also rooted phone can do whatever he likes with the SQLite files.

Comment: I'm specifically talking about the lost of the SQLite file not necessarily the data.

Comment: @ultrasamad clear data would delete the file not only empty it. Default behaviour of SQLiteOpenHelper is to create DB file if it is not present

Answer (score 0):

There is no way that the Android system will erase or remove your file. Database files are stored, along with other app data, under {package_name}/data/data folder so no one except your app can touch it (ignore rooted devices).

Only the following can happen:
1. your code cleared/corrupted the db file
2. user has cleared app data from device settings

Comment: Your code cleared? what do you mean exactly. And in case user cleared app data, will your database data be erased or the file will be deleted?

Comment: 'Your code cleared' means that your code (logic) erased the content of the db file - removed all data. In case the user has cleared data (from settings) the db file will be erased.